# Getting 0 results when querying SO tagged questions with many tags

Tags: bug, tags

Today, I started using this URL as my link to StackOverflow:

[Questions tagged with 1 or more of 36 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%20or%20android%20or%20jquery%20or%20python%20or%20html%20or%20c++%20or%20mysql%20or%20ios%20or%20css%20or%20sql%20or%20asp.net%20or%20objective-c%20or%20iphone%20or%20.net%20or%20ruby-on-rails%20or%20c%20or%20ruby%20or%20sql-server%20or%20ajax%20or%20xml%20or%20asp.net-mvc%20or%20json%20or%20wpf%20or%20linux%20or%20django%20or%20database%20or%20vb.net%20or%20eclipse%20or%20windows%20or%20xcode%20or%20r%20or%20html5%20or%20facebook%20or%20multithreading?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

Some of the time, when I go to the URL, I see that there are zero questions for these tags:

[image: zero results]

Which can't be true. **Note** that the featured questions are still present, though not included in the count to the right. **Also note** that as new questions come in, they show up in the "questions with new activity" notification.

When I refresh the page a couple of times, I will see the correct number of results:

[image: many results]

Can anyone reproduce this bug?

Comment: Reproduced, fixed itself after first refresh.

Comment: Also reproduced, although it took two refreshes.

Comment: I was about to say I couldn't hit it, after a good 15 tries, but I just did and had to refresh a couple times to get questions back up. Could it be that for some reason the query is timing out?

Comment: @Kendra: yes, the query takes too long. It is still completed and cached for the next request to use however.